# Lock resources between multiple builds that run parallel in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Suppose I have a build:

```
Job1:
    Task1: Build
Job2:
dependsOn: Job1
    Task2: Test
```

And the test task uses some kind of database, or another unique resource.

I would like to know if it is possible, when multiple builds are running in parallel, to lock Job2 to run unique without other builds trying to access the same resource.

I am using cmake and ctest, so I know I can do something similar between separate unit tests with [RESOURCE_LOCK](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/prop_test/RESOURCE_LOCK.html), but I am certain that I will not be able to lock that resource between multiple ctest processes.

Comment: You could set global Variables and your first `Task` in `Job2` is a PowerShell skript that poll this global variable and block the Job until it have the expected value?

Comment: Would those global variables be available between two different builds? It's not only within the jobs/tasks.

Comment: over REST API you could define global variables for the complete Azure DevOps scope ([Add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), [Get](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), [Delete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), [Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1))

Comment: Interesting workaround, thanks for the tip. I will try and see if I could something like that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @MarTin's work around. Set one variable with powershell task in `Job1`, then get this variable and use it in job condition for `Job2`.

You don't need to use API to add global variable. There has another easier way can for you try: [Output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks). We expand one feature that customer can configure one output variable and access this output variable in the next job which is depending on the first job.

The sample of set output variable in Job1:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=firstVar;isOutput=true]Job2 Need skip
```

Then get the output variable from Job1 in Job2:

```
Job2Var: $[dependencies.Job1.outputs['outputVars.firstVar']]
```

Then, in job2, you can use it into [job condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job):

```
condition: eq(dependencies.Job1.outputs['outputVars.firstVar'], 'Job2 Need skip')
```

The completed simple sample script look like this:

```
jobs:
- job: Job1
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=firstVar;isOutput=true]Need skip Job2"'
    name: outputVars
- job: Job2
  dependsOn: Job1
  variables:
    Job2Var: $[dependencies.Job1.outputs['outputVars.firstVar'], 'Need skip Job2']
  steps:
  ...
  ...
```

The logic I want to express is dynamically assign values to output variable based on `Job1` and the current pipeline execution state. One specific value represent that the `Job2` should be locked, which means skip its execution. In `Job2`'s condition expression, when the obtained value `$[dependencies.Job1.outputs['outputVars.firstVar']` satisfies the predefined expected value, skip current Job2.

Comment: I believe that output variables will only work if I have my yaml set up with a Job1 and a Job2, but what if two Job1's are running at the same time. Then I believe it is better to set the global variables instead, right?

Comment: @Marnix If I understand correctly, you mean whether the output variable set works while the Job1 running parallel? Just want to confirm, does the job2 which depends on Job1 exists now?

Comment: Let's only have a simple Job1 and you have two machines running it at the same time. There is a chance that they need to lock the resource.

Comment: @Marnix okay. If this, the output variable will workless. Because the output variable only exists between jobs which has dependency relationship. If the actual situation is same with your question described, only this, the output variable can work.